# Using MutableStateOf with enums Kotlin Jetpack Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a state variable of type Enum but I'm not sure how to declare it. I tried the code below and got the error, "Type mismatch: inferred type is MutableState but View was expected".

```
enum class View {
    SIGN_IN,
    LOADING
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MyAppTheme {
            var view: View = remember {
                mutableStateOf(View.LOADING)
            }

            when (view) {
                View.SIGN_IN -> Text(text = "SignIn")
                else -> { Text(text = "Loading") }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `var view: View` is wrong. You can directly use `var viewState = remember { ... }`. This is because the return value is `MutableState` from `remember` but you explicitly typecasted the variable to type `View`.

Comment: @darshan Thank you for your response. I have a follow up question in regard to the `when` statement. I get the error "Comparison of incompatible enums 'MutableState<View>' and 'View' is always unsuccessful" and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @mufsco You can either use `var viewState by remember { ... }` or `when (viewState.value) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `remember` then for `when` you need to fetch the value from state.

```
enum class States {
    SIGN_IN,
    LOADING
}

@Composable
fun Demo() {
    val view = remember {
        mutableStateOf(States.LOADING)
    }

    when (view.value) {
        States.SIGN_IN -> {
            TODO()
        }
        States.LOADING -> {
            TODO()
        }
        else -> {
            // TODO:  
        }
    }
}
```